# Cannot inherit StyleSelector in Silverlight 4 project

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I was given a SL4 project that I just moved to a new machine. The project has a class that inherits StyleSelector to format data in a grid. Even though I have System.Windows.Controls included in my references, I get a missing assembly reference error when I build.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple and obvious. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It turned out that the missing assembly was from a third party control that had not been installed on the new machine. Once I installed the third party controls, the app built with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

SL4/5 doesn't have StyleSelector